# what does the number 1 do in this code

Tags: javascript, hash

I understand (I think) that this JavaScript splits on the hash tag, but what would the 1 represent?

```
window.location.hash.split("#")[1];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The split() method is used to split a string into an array of substrings, and returns the new array.  Thus, the `[1]` represents the second element of the split array `window.location.hash.split("#")[1];`

[JavaScript Split Function](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-split.php)

Answer (score 3):

```
var hashString = "#it #is #easy #to #understand #arrays";

/*
hashString.split("#")[0] = ""
hashString.split("#")[1] = "it "
hashString.split("#")[2] = "is "
hashString.split("#")[3] = "easy "
hashString.split("#")[4] = "to "
hashString.split("#")[5] = "understand "
hashString.split("#")[6] = "arrays"
*/
```

The reason why split("#")[0] is an empty string is because the split function encounters a "#" at the very start of the string, at which point it creates an entry into the array that includes every character it has passed so far, with the exception of the "#".  Since it has passed no characters so far, it creates an entry that is an empty string.

Here's another example:

```
var hashString = "it #is #easy #to #understand #arrays";

/*
hashString.split("#")[0] = "it "
hashString.split("#")[1] = "is "
hashString.split("#")[2] = "easy "
hashString.split("#")[3] = "to "
hashString.split("#")[4] = "understand "
hashString.split("#")[5] = "arrays"
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

It accesses the second element found from the split.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to strip off the hash (`#`) is...

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

`split()` returns an array, `[1]` grabs the 2nd element in the array `[0]` would grab the first element.